# How to pass null argument to a Java method from native code

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am currently trying to debug a problem we are having with a Java logger that is being called from our native code.

```
/* convert C to Java String */
java_string = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, string);

/* call log method on logger instance */
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, logger, log_method_id, java_string);
```

Looking at the Java code I can see that if java_string was erroneously null, this could potentially cause us problems. I wanted to temporarily hack the above code to return a Java null to compare the resulting failure against what we see in the field. How can I make java_string be a Java null?

I have tried the following:-

```
/* convert C to Java String */
java_string = NULL;

/* call log method on logger instance */
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, logger, log_method_id, java_string);
```

but this appears to result in the string "null" being sent to the Java method.

Just to be clear, I have no intention of deliberately passing null to this method, I only want to test what would happen with the resulting NullPointerException since we are calling the Java code from C.

Comment: *"but this appears to result in the string "null" being sent to the Java method"* Are you sure about that? It's not that the logger is detecting the `null` and handling it? That seems more likely, frankly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm fairly certain. At the Java side the logger compares the message against the last message using the equals method. It does this before printing the logging message. Since it survives this step I figured the message coming in couldn't be null.

Comment: @ Strawberry: It depends, if it was `lastMessage.equals(thisMessage)`, then `thisMessage` being `null` wouldn't be a problem. But `thisMessage.equals(lastMessage)` would, of course, throw an NPE. The gold standard, of course, is set a breakpoint on the first line of that method and actually look at the argument.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the input, I'm taking a look with a debugger now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My apologies, you are correct. The underlying logger does tolerate a null and converts it to a string null. So I do believe the JNI NULL argument is being interpreted as a Java null in the Java code.